# Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Tags: python, function

```
TB_data_EMR = TB_data[TB_data["g_whoregion"] == "EMR"]
e_inc_num_by_EMRyear = []
for x in list_of_years:
    def data_by_year(x):
        TB_data_EMRyear = TB_data_EMR[TB_data_EMR["year"]==x]
        return TB_data_EMRyear["e_inc_num"].sum()
    e_inc_num_by_EMRyear.append(data_by_year(x))
```

I need to repeat this code for all catagories in my "`g_whoregion`" column.  Is there a good way to create function to accomplish this task rather than retyping the code and simply substituting in the different category names as shown below:

```
TB_data_AFR = TB_data[TB_data["g_whoregion"] == "AFR"]
e_inc_num_by_AFRyear = []
for x in list_of_years:
    def data_by_year(x):
        TB_data_AFRyear = TB_data_AFR[TB_data_AFR["year"]==x]
        return TB_data_AFRyear["e_inc_num"].sum()
    e_inc_num_by_AFRyear.append(data_by_year(x))
```

Ideally,  I would love a data frame that contains the total "`e_inc_num`" (incident cases) by "`year`" for each region in "`g_whoregion`" if that makes sense, but I have no idea how to accomplish that.  My end goal is to create a line plot showing incidence in a given year for each different region.

Comment: Identify what is the same and what is different. Create a single function of what is the same. Parameterise it with the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify what is the same and what is different. Create a single function of what is the same. Parameterise it with the differences.

```
def regions_by_year(tb_data_region_type):
    TB_data_region = TB_data[TB_data["g_whoregion"] == tb_data_region_type]
    e_inc_num = []
    for x in list_of_years:
        def data_by_year(x):
            TB_data_region_year = TB_data_region[TB_data_region["year"]==x]
            return TB_data_region_year["e_inc_num"].sum()
        e_inc_num.append(data_by_year(x))
   return e_inc_num
```

Then you can use it:

```
emr = regions_by_year('EMR')
afr = regions_by_year('AFR')
```

edit:

You could shorten the function to use a list comprehension. It's concise but pretty readable:

```
def regions_by_year(tb_data_region_type):
    TB_data_region = TB_data[TB_data["g_whoregion"] == tb_data_region_type]

    return [TB_data_region[TB_data_region["year"]==year]["e_inc_num"].sum()
            for year in years]
```